# How to perform all CRUD operations using a single view in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring-MVC, i created an application for performing CRUD operations, with separate views for insert,update and delete and view.
Now my requirement is i need all these in a single view( A form for collecting data, and a grid or table below which updates and shows the entire table as the user submits the above form).
But i also want to include options in the table for edit and delete ad when i click on edit the data in that row should auto populate in the form above the table, the same for delete also.
How to bring in this requirement.
Is there a tutorial or example for this...

Answer (score 0):

The internet is full of tutorials, try to search the one who fits your requirements best. Maybe this tutorial can help you:

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example

you can start with this and then you can adapt it to your requirement in case.

Comment: I learned from this tutorial to create a CRUD application, but i couldn't figure out a way to adapt to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Crud operations with Spring MVC and MySql database.
https://github.com/javabycode/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example

Comment: thanks for the link!.
But all those tutorials use separate views for each CRUD operation, i'm trying to figure out how to perform insert update view and delete in a single view?